# How to open a background App using a silent push from a web site button

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to use a web based API push service like "Boxcar" linked to a button in my web page, to send a silent push to my iphone in which the iPhone will interrupt the currently running app, and reopen (previously opened/in background) the linked app with the push's updated info?

So in all: open an app, go to another app (such as Twitter), then on my web page press a button and have Twitter interrupted and brought back to the original app with updated data from the push.

Another question would be, do I need a third party API to accomplish this, or can I use purely apple code?

I am a fairly new programmer and very new to APN's and app building, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to SO!

Unfortunately, there is no way to open up applications from the background programmatically in iOS. Apple leaves that to the user. You would have to send a push to the phone that the user interacts with in order to open up the app to a specific page. The only way you can open up another app is using URL Schemes (see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

The problem with that is you can only do it from YOUR app to someone else's app (or if you have a widely enough used app, some people might even link to yours, although I'm not sure Twitter would ever do that).

Basically what URL Schemes do is allow the phone to open up a URL as if it were a website. Before it loads the webpage, it checks to see if any apps respond to that URL. For instance, if you wanted to open Maps to a specific location:

```
NSString *title = @"title";
float latitude = 35.4634;
float longitude = 9.43425;
int zoom = 13;
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@@%1.6f,%1.6f&z=%d", title, latitude, longitude, zoom];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I really appreciate it. So there is no way for it to open programmatically and interrupt the running app? There would have to be the user clicking on it for it do that through a URL scheme? Even though opening up the app itself is the user interacting with the app? Thanks for the response @AlexKoren

Comment: This is just a proof-of-concept project, it doesn't need to follow any rules because its not for the app store. Let me know if that changes anything. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't unless you've jailbroken your device.